# Nomes iguais extensões de arquivos diferentes

Tags: python-3.x

tenho um diretório com 2000 arquivos, muitos tem o mesmo nome e extensão diferente,
ex:
diff001.txt
diff001.pdf
diff003.txt
diff013.txt
diff014.pdf
diff021.txt
diff021.pdf
neste caso gostaria de ficar apenas com o arquivo com a extensão txt e excluir o pdf.

Não tenho ideia como faze-lo.
Obrigado.

Comment: Não é mais fácil fazer do OS? Por exemplo a partir do zsh: `rm -- *.pdf(e'{[ -e $REPLY:r.txt]}')`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazê-lo, segue  uma delas:

```
import os

path = 'COLOQUE_AQUI_O_PATH_PARA_DIRETORIO_COM_ARQUIVOS'

txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('txt') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]
```

Esta forma acima de *list comprehension* equivale a:

```
txt_files = []

for f in os.listdir(path):
     if f.endswith('txt') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f):
         txt_files.append(f)
```

**Nota** Esta solução não leva em consideração subdiretórios uma vez que não foi solicitado na pergunta

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia explicar o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta?

Comment: Eu não votei nem na pergunta e nem nas respostas, só fiz o fechamento por não ser um problema de programação pois essa atividade se resolve com uma linha num terminal, talvez a linha mais verbosa seja no power shell mas mesmo assim uma linha. E talvez por isso os negativos.